# Does one have the right or just the privilege to extend the PhD study period due to parental leave?

Tags: phd, sweden

Assuming somebody is employed as a PhD student, I found several references to PhD study period and parental leave, but the wording is rather weak.

> The study period **may** only be extended if there are special reasons for it. Such grounds **may** be due to illness, leave for military service, work for trade unions and student organizations or parental leave. Ordinance (2010:1064). [automatically translated, highlights mine]

Notice *may* instead of *must*.

The [Regulations for doctoral studies at Umeå University](http://www.umu.se/digitalAssets/95/95605_regulations-for-doctoral-studies.pdf) states:

> 5.4.  Parental    leave
>
> ● Parental leave shall always be reported to the employer in accordance with applicable law and agreements.
>
> ● When
>   parental leave is cited as a special reason for extension of a
>   doctoral studentship or term of a doctoral grant, the period of
>   parental leave is counted from the day it is validated.
>
> **The Dean makes the decisions on these matters.**
>   [highlights mine]

Notice that the Dean has the final word.

The [PhD Student FAQ](http://www.sus.su.se/doktorandombud/en/faq) from the Stockholm University Student Union uses stronger wording:

> This means that you have the **right** to get prolongation for the time that you are on parental leave so that you don’t lose out of any time for your research.

Can anybody point me to a regulation, a legal precedent or anything similar clarifying whether prolongation of PhD study period is a right or a privilege?

Comment: Interesting question. I am almost certain that it is a right, especially given the generally very beneficial Swedish laws in this area (and it is at least my understanding that it is a right in Denmark which tends to have slightly less beneficial rules, though only slightly).

Comment: Anecdotally: I had two PhD student colleagues who took parental leave during their PhD studies.  Both were extended.  This was as Luleå University of Technology.  However, I don't know to what degree this extension was their legal right or university policy.  It may well be that all universities share this policy and that in absence of a conflict, the legal right has not been tested in court.

Comment: *"Can anybody point me to a regulation, a legal precedent or anything similar clarifying whether prolongation of PhD study period is a right or a privilege?"* I assume you specifically mean "for Sweden", correct? Legal procedures almost certainly differ elsewhere in the world. Most importantly, I am not sure whether the concept of a "study period" within which you need to have finished even exists in many countries, making this a bit of a mood point.

Comment: How are you funded? Is the student an employee of the university? Or a student but has outside funding?

Comment: Assume the PhD student is an employee of the university. (However, I would be curious as to what applies to PhD students on stipend.)

Answer (score -3):

The word 'may' does not preclude refusal. It means, it is possible to extend.

In academia, in general, if there is good reason for extension of PhD, it is always allowed. Pregnancy is a good ground for extension and it would be very rare for a student to be penalised for getting pregnant.

Comment: This answer does not sound very certain. Also, it might as well be the father that wishes to take parental leave, rather than the mother.

Comment: True, but this wording is exactly why it is unclear whether prolongation is a right or privilege.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, rather further explains the uncertainty.

Comment: _In academia, in general, if there is good reason for extension of PhD, it is always allowed._ — This is not even approximately true.

Comment: Let me clarify:
1. There is a dearth of women in STEM. In order to promote a more women-friendly academic environment, progressive Universities allow for suspension of PhD in case of : maternity, serious & certified illness,

2. Maternity is almost always a right of women, not a privilege that men can consider case by case or deny it.

3. A search for 'Suspend PhD maternity' brings up policies of Universities and almost all ranked Universities allow suspension of PhD course.

4. Further, an analysis of laws and court verdicts have universally upheld women rights to maternity leave.